# Mac full screen app, bring other app's window in as auxiliary window

Tags: macos, osx-lion, nswindow

I have an app with a full screen NSWindow, using the `toggleFullScreen:` API introduced in Lion. I know that you can have auxiliary windows floating over your full screen window.

What I would like to do is pull in another app's window — in this case a New Email window from Mail.app that I've invoked using the Scripting Bridge — so that it floats atop my full screen window.

I am fine with using any APIs that are available, whether they're App Store safe or no. (If there *is* a public API solution, I'd rather use that, but private are fine if not.)